# Font Size relative to container Height - Help convert from vanilla to TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a resizable box in an angular project, which has some text inside a paragraph, and I need a method to make the text font-size dynamic to fill the whole container all the time.
I found a fiddle with an example in vanilla, but I haven't been able to convert it to TypeScript and make it work on my project.

This is the fiddle showing my purpose and the function I want to convert to TypeScript.

```
var autoSizeText;

autoSizeText = function() {
  var el, elements, i, len, results;
  elements = $('.resize');
  console.log(elements);
  if (elements.length < 0) {
    return;
  }
  results = [];
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = elements[i];
    results.push((function(el) {
      var resizeText, results1;
      resizeText = function() {
        var elNewFontSize;
        elNewFontSize = (parseInt($(el).css('font-size').slice(0, -2)) - 1) + 'px';
        return $(el).css('font-size', elNewFontSize);
      };
      results1 = [];
      while (el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        results1.push(resizeText());
      }
      return results1;
    })(el));
  }
  return results;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return autoSizeText();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k0gqhq0s/

knowing that I'll be executing it on a method where I have access to paragraph element, the text inside it, its container and the current font size.

my code is this:

```
  <quill-editor
    #textEditor
    *ngIf="editMode"
    (dblclick)="readOnly = false;"
    [readOnly]="readOnly"
    [attr.draghandler]="readOnly"
    [(ngModel)]="image.text"
    [modules]="editorConfig"
    (onContentChanged)="checkHeightChanges($event, image)"
    theme="bubble"
    style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
```

and I want to execute that autoSizeText method on this event onContentChanged().

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show some effort first :] Maybe provide the code you have know and ask concrete questions about it...

Comment: There's no document.Ready in Angular. It's infinitely updating the view on user changes.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll be executing it on an input change event.

Comment: then you should write a directive that is listening on input change

Comment: Yes that&#39;s something I can do, my problem is writing this autosize function logic in typescript.